# Converting .xml into .xlsx python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to find out the best way to work with an .xml file in python but any option given in the internet worked for me, so I've tried to open it manually with excel and I everything worked perfect, so I have the following idea but I'm getting an error that I don't know how to fix it.

This is the code:

```
with open("file.xml", "rb") as f1:
    with open("file.xlsx", "wb") as f2:
        f2.write(f1.read())
        f2.close()
```

The file is correctly saved as an excel file but when I try the following:

```
orders = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
print(orders)
```

I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

If I open it manually with excel I can see the file without problems and if I save it I can open it with pandas too.

I don't need it in excel format, but that was the only solution that worked for me to use it as dataframe.

Do you guys have any recommendation?

Comment: Your file corrupted for whatever reason probably. You could try a CSV instead of an Excel file if the actual type doesn't matter.

Comment: is the end goal a dataframe? why not go from xml to a dataframe?

Comment: I've tried it to convert it directly from xml to dataframe but I couldn't. All the .xml examples on internet that I find are different to mine.